# LinkedIn API needs 5 seconds of delay between auth and request

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I wrote an oAuth2 process with LinkedIn, and after I get the authentication token, if I make a request I get the following response:

> Then token used in this request has been revoked by the user.

However, if I just do:

```
await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000))
```

and then make the request, it works just fine.
If I log the request's url, and then try it manually, still works.

The token has an expiration of 2 months.

How can I make the request directly after authenticating, instead of waiting 5 seconds? (tried 3 seconds, didn't work)

This is the code in broad strokes, using `simple-oauth2`:

```
    const result = await this.client.authorizationCode.getToken({
      code: req.query.code,
      redirect_uri: this.redirect_uri
    });
    console.log('Result', result);
    const accessToken = this.client.accessToken.create(result);
    console.log({ accessToken: accessToken.token.access_token });

    await wait(5000);

    const profile = await this.profile(accessToken.token.access_token);
```

Comment: Could you include your code for the full oAuth process?

Comment: @Caffeinated.tech I've added it

Comment: Your code looks correct. I'm not sure what else could be happening unless your system time is out of sync, or there are some other async methods changing some related variables in the background